# Smart Contract Deployment Failed PowerShell

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-compile

A beginner smart contract developer here. This is my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        uint8 vote;
       // address delegate;
    }
    struct Proposal {
        uint voteCount; // could add other data about proposal
    }

    address chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) voters;
    Proposal[] proposals;


    /// Create a new ballot with $(_numProposals) different proposals.
    constructor(uint8 _numProposals) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 2;
        proposals.length = _numProposals; 
    }

    /// Give $(toVoter) the right to vote on this ballot.
    /// May only be called by $(chairperson).
    function register(address toVoter) public {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[toVoter].voted) return;
        voters[toVoter].weight = 1;
        voters[toVoter].voted = false;
    }

    /// Give a single vote to proposal $(toProposal).
    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= proposals.length) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public view returns (uint8 _winningProposal,uint wvc) {
        uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint8 prop = 0; prop < proposals.length; prop++)
            if (proposals[prop].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[prop].voteCount;
                _winningProposal = prop;
                wvc=winningVoteCount;
            }
    }     
}
```

While compiling using Truffle compile I don't get any errors as below:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================

    > Compiling .\contracts\Ballot.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
    > Artifacts written to C:\Users\Aaryamann\Desktop\simpleAddress\build\contracts
    > Compiled successfully using:
       - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang
```

However, when I use `truffle migrate --reset` this happens:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================

    > Compiling .\contracts\Ballot.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
    > Artifacts written to C:\Users\Aaryamann\Desktop\simpleAddress\build\contracts
    > Compiled successfully using:
       - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



Starting migrations...
======================

    > Network name:    'development'
    > Network id:      5777
    > Block gas limit: 0x6691b7


1_initial_migration.js
======================

       Replacing 'Migrations'
       ----------------------
       > transaction hash:    0xee307d9e6aa87830ba37b60d5e5a5fc0de67ed6f307f23a86bf9fea715b4ecc0
       > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
       > contract address:    0xFd69eD8A7425792183a50B2433E5260efC68ad16
       > block number:        1
       > block timestamp:     1586275003
       > account:             0xe266322C7F15539244BCcF0Ac2e8C0918fc9d5D7
       > balance:             99.9967165
       > gas used:            164175
       > gas price:           20 gwei
       > value sent:          0 ETH
       > total cost:          0.0032835 ETH


       > Saving migration to chain.
       > Saving artifacts
       -------------------------------------
       > Total cost:           0.0032835 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================



     Deploying 'Ballot'
       ------------------

    Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

    "Ballot" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!.

        at C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:364:1
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
        at Migration._deploy (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:70:1)
        at Migration._load (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:57:1)
        at Migration.run (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:167:1)
        at Object.runMigrations (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:148:1)
        at Object.runFrom (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:110:1)
        at Object.runAll (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:114:1)
        at Object.run (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:79:1)
        at runMigrations (C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:253:1)
        at C:\Users\Aaryamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:218:1
    Truffle v5.1.20 (core: 5.1.20)
    Node v13.12.0
```

It's running on PowerShell.

Comment: we need your migration file.. you contract expect a parameter when you deploy it. will look something like this 
await deployer.deploy(Ballot, <your parameter>);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself is fine and therefore compiles successfully. However when you try to deploy the contract in *2_deploy_contracts.js* it gives an error.

Your contract requires one constructor argument `uint8 _numProposals` which you need to provide in *2_deploy_contracts.js*. So instead of something like `deployer.deploy(A)` you need something like `deployer.deploy(A, 8)` where `8` is the argument.

You can read more about Truffle's constructor arguments syntax here: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-